# Using tkinter button command from other class

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to select more directory in same windows. For selection of directory I prepared class `SelectDir`. This object I call from class `Gui` (by using `SelectDir`. `OpenDirWnd()`). Now I can not obtain name of directory from class `SelectDir` for `tk.Entry` in class `Gui`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

class SelectDir():
   def __init__(self,master, title,dirInit):
       self.dir_opt = options = {}

       self.dirInit          = dirInit
       options['parent']     = master
       options['title']      = title
       options['initialdir'] = self.dirInit
       self.master           = master
       self.dirSelect        = tk.StringVar()
       self.dirSelect.set(self.dirInit)

   def OpenDirWnd(self):
       self.master.grab_set()
       self.dirSelect = askdirectory(**self.dir_opt)
       if self.dirSelect == "":
           self.dirSelect.set(self.dirInit)

   def NameSelectDir(self):
       return self.dirSelect

class Gui(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        frMaster = tk.Frame(master)

        seldir = SelectDir(master, " Select directory",
                           "D:\\MyPgm\\Python\\Tiles_8")
        button = tk.Button(frMaster,text=">>>",command = seldir.OpenDirWnd )
        frMaster.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.35)
        button.grid(column = 0, row=0)
        self.actDir = tk.StringVar()

        self.actDir.set("D:\\MyPgm\\Python\\Tiles_8")
        entry= tk.Entry(frMaster,textvariable = self.actDir,width = 30)
        entry.grid(column = 0, row=1)

wndRoot = tk.Tk()
appapp = Gui(master=wndRoot)
appapp.mainloop()
```

Comment: you should create function in `Gui` and assign to `button` and this function should use `SelectDir` and later get information from `SelectDir` and put in `Entry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create function in `Gui` and assign to button - and this function should use `SelectDir` to show window and later get information from `SelectDir` and put in `Entry`

BTW: I changed some code (ie. names because we prefer lower_case names for functions/methods and variables and CamelCase names for classes. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

# --- classes ---

class SelectDir():

   def __init__(self, master, title, initial):
       self.master = master

       self.initial = initial
       self.selected = initial

       self.options = {
            'parent': master,
            'title': title,
            'initialdir': initial,
       }

   def show(self):
       result = askdirectory(**self.options)
       if result:
           self.selected = result
           #self.options['initialdir'] = result
       # or
       #return self.selected

   def get(self):
       return self.selected


class Gui(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.seldir = SelectDir(self, "Select directory", "D:\\MyPgm\\Python\\Tiles_8")

        button = tk.Button(frame, text=">>>", command=self.select_dir)
        button.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.act_dir = tk.StringVar()
        self.act_dir.set("D:\\MyPgm\\Python\\Tiles_8")

        entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.act_dir, width=30)
        entry.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def select_dir(self):
        self.seldir.show()
        self.act_dir.set(self.seldir.get())
        # or
        #result = seldir.show()
        #self.act_dir.set(result)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
app = Gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I test it.